# How to declare a variable as the value of another variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to declare a variable as the value of a separate value.

I am trying to make a custom class for a 2D array with a variable number of rows. To do this each of the separate rows need a name. As the number of rows are determined on runtime i need to name the rows using variables.

```
class row {
    public:
    int ID;
    node content;
};
class varArray
{
public:
    int numRows = 0;
    row *rowVals;
    row addRows(node rowData);

};
```

this is my header file for the classes i need to do this

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "varArray.h"




row varArray::addRows(node rowData)
{
    row::numRows++;
    row::ID = row::numRows;
}
```

this is the main code file for my class

as you most likely know `row::ID = row::numRows;`displays the "error a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object." The only way i can think of to solve this is to name each row and varArray using the value of a separate variable.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am trying to assign the name of a variable as the value of another.  For example   ````int ID = 5;  int ID;```` and then have the second ID have the name of 5.

Comment: Names of variables cannot be set at run time. ???

Comment: I assume `rowVals` is meant to be a dynamic array of `row` objects, and `numRows` is meant to count how many exist, and that OP is trying to make a `row` and add it to the `rowVals` collection

Comment: If the name of the variables cannot be set at runtime do you have any other suggestions for making an unknown amount of variables in C++ as i am trying to make some code that will work off a file specified at runtime and I will need a certain number of variables for for the amount of information in the file

Comment: @CampbellRowland We use arrays and `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to name the rows.. index of the row should be sufficient as an identifier.
If it's really required to store an ID in the row object itself, you can do this in addRows

> ++this.numRows;
>
> row r;
>
> r.ID = this.numRows;
>
> ...code to add the row data to rowVals...

Comment: Wouldnt ```` row.ID;```` at ````row.ID=this.numRows;````have the error "a non static member reference must be relative to a specific object"

Comment: I think it's assumed that `row` would be an object of type `row`, so it's poorly named. Probably meant `row r; r.ID = ++this.numRows;` or something

Comment: @Tas you are right. row was meant to be object not class name. Changed the answer.. changed the var name to r.

Comment: The only problem with that is the number of rows I would need would be decided at runtime and I would not be able to create all the rows before runtime as you suggest as the amount I would need would be decided based on the number of nodes(a separate custom class) created in the code(which generates the same problem of having an unknown number of variables). Would the vector class be helpful for this task?

Comment: Yes you 100% want `std::vector<row>` it will trivialise the whole thing